# Is it possible to easily re-organize C++ functions within VS2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-organization

Is there any way to easily organize my C++ functions within Visual Studio 2013? My Data Structures course requires that all functions be sorted alphabetically as part of the coding standard, and doing it by hand is getting very tiresome.

EDIT: Here is the relevant part of the coding standard, for those who are interested.

5. FUNCTIONS

5.1 Function prototypes should be defined in the header file.[1]

5.2 Function definitions should be defined in the implementation file.[1]

**5.3 All function prototypes and definitions must be sorted in ascending order based on function names.[2]**

5.4 Functions should be small and concise to avoid developing overly complex functions.

5.5 Functions must be separated by at least one blank line.

5.6 Functions must have the following statements:

> i. Pre: What are the conditions needed before calling this function?
>
> ii. Post: What are the conditions after the function is completed?
>
> iii. Purpose: What is this function supposed to do?
>
> iv. Author: Who implemented this function? This is needed only if the
>   project is completed in a team setting

Example:

```
/* Pre: None
 * Post: Welcome displayed to the screen
 * Purpose: Display Greeting message to the user
 *********************************************************/

void sayHi()
{
    cout << "Welcome\n";
}
```

[1] If the project is large enough, otherwise not needed.

**[2] For class member functions, the functions should be list in ascending order within their own section.**

Comment: Come on, do it by hand. Don't be lazy. Learn!

Comment: If I had this rather unusual coding standard I would try to create the functions in alphabetical order instead of reorganizing the code afterwards. To answer your question I have not seen such an application in the 30+ years that I have been a programmer.

Comment: @Ajay, you dont know the size of his codebase. It may not be feasible

Comment: If its for a data structures class the codebase I would assume is less than 1000 lines..

Comment: std::string, getline and stack are your friends. Use std::string to store lines. Use getline to fetch lines and use stacks to keep track of curly braces.

Comment: That is the most bizarre, arbitrary and nonsensical 'coding standard' I have ever heard of, almost.

Comment: Refactoring... prepending an a at the first function, b at the second and so on... ;-) just kidding

Comment: Its a fun coding exercise. I agree that the standard is stupid.

Comment: @Ajay I already did all of the learning when i was designing and writing the program. Now i have to do a bunch of mindless ctrl+c-ctrl+v-ing, which is neither fun nor educational.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes it is under 1000 lines (usually around 500), but when you need to do it for EVERY assignment, it starts getting very tedious.

Comment: Maybe they want you to think of the function names before you start coding (design first). If you do that you can start out with stubs then fill in the implementation..

Comment: @user3670482 I will consider writing a program to do it for me if i have any free time, which is unlikely as the semester is entering its final few weeks. It also doesn't help that public and private functions need to be separated into two different alphabetized sections.

Comment: @user3670482 One issue with creating a tool to do this for me is that extracting the name of a function from its header can be difficult. Because i'm using templated functions most of my headers look like this: `template <typename T>
void BST<T>::displayTree(Queue<BST_Node<T>*> *queue, int tab, int count)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collapse functions using the '+' icon in the left-hand margin.

Then you can either drag them up and down or place the cursor on the collapsed line and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> to move them.

If you collapse everything to start with it greatly simplifies the process.

**EDIT:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to collapse all
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to expand all

Comment: Is it possible to collapse all functions within a file?

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but definitely the best one available until someone writes a tool to do this task automatically. By the way, how exactly do you drag the functions?

Comment: @android927 With the line collapsed you can click in the margin to the left (but not on the '+') to select a line. Once the Line is selected you can drag and drop it.

Comment: Or more plausibly, until the crazy person who wrote this coding standard retires and it is changed.

Comment: @MartinBonner Sounds like you're against this behavior. I'm a pretty big fan personally, but I get this is just an editor behavior, so different strokes for different folks I suppose.

Comment: @JonathanMee:  Good guess.  Alphabetically seems like a rather poor ordering to me.  For example, if I was writing a bignum class, I'd want to put `operator /(lhs,rhs)` right next to `operator *` - not separated by +/-.  And I want to put the copy assignment operator right next to the copy constructor, etc, etc.  (Basically, sort by function, not by name).

Comment: @MartinBonner So you're saying you're opposed to the alphabetical sorting, not the ability to move functions around like this... I can see that. But I can also appreciate the idea of alphabetical ordering, it makes it easy to understand the ordering where non-alphabetical schemes are subject to the whims of the coder. For example, should `int getBar()` be followed by `void setBar(int)` or by `int getFoo()`?

Comment: Ah yes.  The ability to move functions around is very useful.  As to finding functions, that's what your IDE/editor does isn't ?

Comment: @MartinBonner Good point, Visual Studio has the insanely annoying habit of starting up in global space so I can't immediately select a method from it's drop-downs at the top of the editor. Consequentially I frequently find myself scrolling to the function rather than just jumping to it. I guess I'm saying the reason I care about function order is cause my IDE is annoying... hmmm... that's an ominous thought.